# How can I enable in mysql the query logging?

Tags: mysql

Im using  Mysql Server 5.7 Community Edition.
I want to log all the server query requests. In my.ini file:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
long_query_time=0.5
slow_query_log_file=C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/logs/slowquery.log 
slow-query-log=1
log-error=C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/logs/error.log
```

I cant see anything in my log files. Why?

Comment: I have tried many things, but neither of them works.

Comment: Can you elaborate on some of the things you've tried?  It is difficult to help you diagnose this issue if we have no idea what hasn't worked, and those who help you will spend a lot of time retracing steps you've already tried.

Comment: I have read a lot of articles about how should I turn on the query log, but neither of them worked. All of my log files are empty. My question is: Would it work whit the settings I've written?